# ElasticSearch Indexing - Selecting java objects for indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can someone let me know on what basis we should select which java entity object should of type "INDEX" in elasticsearch and which object should be of type "TYPE" ??

Let us have object 1, 2, 3

Object 1 has list of Object 2. Object 3 is another separate object.

In this case which should be "INDEX" and which should be "TYPE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually depends on you. You can create a separate index for all domains or you can create `index` with the name of your application or something.Then you can define types inside it which will contain domains of your application.

As per your case you can define `Object1` and `Object3` as type.
Since `Object2` is contained in Object1, you will have to define it either as `object` field or `nested` field inside type `Object1` .

SO your architecture would be like

`Name Of Index` : `indexName`

`indexName` Types     : `object1` and `object3`

`object1` will have [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) or [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-object-type.html) fieldtype of `object2`.

Steps would be..

- `PUT /indexName`
- `PUT indexName/object1/_mapping
     {
        "properties": {
         "object2": {
        "type": "nested" //this can be "object" as well
      }
    }
  }`
- `PUT indexName/object3/_mapping
     {
        "properties": {
        ...
    }
  }`

Hope this helps

Comment: Which is good ? To have as a nested object or just another inner element

Comment: It depends on your requirement. Read the difference between both at https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch to see which one to use.